# Show that $\dim \operatorname{im}(f) + \dim \ker(f) = \dim V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V,W$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces and $f$ is linear mapping from $V$ to $W$. Show that $\dim \operatorname{im}(f) + \dim \ker(f) = \dim V.$

---

Here is what I did. Please kindly give me a recommendation or help me to show this. Thank in advance!

Let $(e_1,e_2, \dots, e_n)$ be a basis for $V$ and $(e_1,e_2, \dots, e_k)$ be a basis for $\ker(f),k<n$.

We can get $$\dim V=n,\quad \dim \ker(f)=k$$
Then we need to prove that $\dim \operatorname{im}(f)=n-k$

Since $(e_1,e_2, \dots,e_n)$ is basis for $V$. $(e_1,e_2, \dots,e_n)$ spans V.

Let $x\in V$.There exists $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{K}$ such that
$$x=\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+\cdots+\lambda_ne_n$$
$f$ is linear mapping
$$f(x)=f(\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+\cdots+\lambda_ne_n)$$
$$f(x)=\lambda_1f(e_1)+\lambda_2f(e_2)+\cdots+\lambda_nf(e_n)$$
Which that $\operatorname{im}(f)=\{f(v)\in W | v\in V\}$
$$\operatorname{im}(f)=\operatorname{span}\{f(e_1),f(e_2),\dots,f(e_n)\}$$
Since $(e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n)$ is linearly independent.There exists $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k,\dots\alpha_n\in\mathbb{K},\quad k<n$

Which $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\dots=\alpha_n=0$
$$\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\cdots+\alpha_ke_k+\alpha_{k+1}e_{k+1}+\cdots+\alpha_ne_n=0$$
$$f(\alpha_1e_1+\alpha_2e_2+\cdots+\alpha_ke_k+\alpha_{k+1}e_{k+1}+\cdots+\alpha_ne_n)=f(0)$$
$$\alpha_1f(e_1)+\alpha_2f(e_2)+\cdots+\alpha_kf(e_k)+\alpha_{k+1}f(e_{k+1})+\cdots+\alpha_nf(e_n)=0$$
Since $\ker(f)=\operatorname{span}\{e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k\}\Longrightarrow f(e_1)=f(e_2)=\dots=f(e_k)=0$.We can get
$$\alpha_{k+1}f(e_{k+1})+\cdots+\alpha_nf(e_n)=0$$
So that $\{f(e_{k+1}),\dots,f(e_n)\}$ is linearly independent.

We can get $\{f(e_{k+1}),\dots,f(e_n)\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{im}(f)\Longrightarrow \dim \operatorname{im}(f)=n-k$.

Comment: $V/\ker(f)\cong\text{im}(f)$.

Comment: Should I add or do anything more on my proof?

Comment: @LaVendEr  I think you had a typo - I changed it. Compare to see that you agree?

Comment: @311411 yeah I changed

Comment: No this would not fly... You have to show 1) $f(e_{k+1}), \cdots f(e_{n})$ span $f(V)$ and 2) $f(e_{k+1}), \cdots f(e_n)$ are independent. Your argument should have these two parts addressed explicitly [you have part 1 somewhat implicitly]. For Part 2), (presumably after finishing with part 1 ) you should start off with something like "Suppose we have a relation $\alpha_{k+1} f(e_{k+1}) + \cdots +\alpha_n f(e_n) =0.$"  and, then, after an argument, CONCLUDE that the $\alpha_{k+1}=\cdots = \alpha_n = 0$. Together, 1) and 2) imply that $f(e_{k+1}), \cdots, f(e_n)$ forms a basis for the image.

Comment: Also, small note, just for the sake of writing, I think you should introduce the basis for $\ker f$ first, and then say you extend it to a basis of $V$, to make clear that these are intended to be the "same" $e_i$ (and so you don't have to sort of "retroactively" make the first $k$ of $(e_i)_{i=1}^n$ a basis for $\ker f$ after you've already introduced them.)

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you're allowed to assume, but I think about it like this. $\mathrm{Ker}(f) = K$ is a linear subspace and together with its orthogonal complement, the direct product spans $V$:
$$
V = K \oplus K^\perp
$$

Since $f$ restricted to $K^\perp$ is a linear function with trivial kernel, it is necessaritly true that $\left. f \right|_{K^{\perp}}$ is injective. This implies that $\mathrm{dim} \, K^\perp = \mathrm{dim} \, f(K^\perp)$.

The desired result follows from the fact that the dimension of $V$ is equal to the sum of the dimensions of the spaces in any equivalent direct product.

So:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{dim}  \, V & = \mathrm{dim}  \, K \oplus K^\perp \\
 & =  \mathrm{dim}  \, K + \mathrm{dim} \, K^{\perp} \\
 & = \mathrm{dim} \, K + \mathrm{dim} \, f(K^{\perp}) \\
 & = \mathrm{dim} \, K + \mathrm{dim} \, f(V) \\
 & = \mathrm{dim} \, \mathrm{Ker}(f) + \mathrm{dim} \, \mathrm{Im}(f) 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Not every vector space is an inner product space.

Comment: Fair enough. But they're finite dimensional, so they should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, right?

Comment: Not if the ground field is not $\mathbb{R}$. Do you see anything in the problem stating that this is a real or complex vector space? I don’t. The result holds over arbitrary fields, and in fact holds in infinite dimension as well.

Comment: Also a good point

Comment: It doesn't need to be an *orthogonal* complement. Any complement of $\ker f$ will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is better than mine because yours deals with linear transformations. I'm just giving you another perspective. Let $A$ be the $m\times n$ matrix for $f$ (wrt any choice of bases). Let $r$ be the rank of $A.$
$$\dim \operatorname{im}(f)=\dim(\text{column space of }A)=r$$
$\dim \ker(f) = n-r= $ the number of parameters when solving $AX=0.$